# C++ Unable to increase size of .text section

Tags: c++, portable-executable

I am attempting to increase the size of the .text section of an executable.

```
int main()
{
    DWORD dwSize,
          dwFileOffset,
          dwFileSize;

    ifstream in;

    BYTE* pData,
        * pContents;

    bool bAdjust = false;

    DWORD dwDataPointer;

    IMAGE_DOS_HEADER* dosHeader;

    IMAGE_NT_HEADERS* ntHeader;

    IMAGE_SECTION_HEADER* sectionHeader;

    vector<byte> data;

    vector<byte>::iterator dataIterator;


    in.open("C:\\MineSweeper.exe", ios::in | ios::binary);

    if(in.is_open() == true)
    {
        in.seekg(0, ios::end);
        dwFileSize = in.tellg();
        in.seekg(0, ios::beg);

        pContents = new BYTE[dwFileSize];
        in.read((char*)pContents, dwFileSize);
        in.close();


        for(int i = 0; i < dwFileSize; i++)
            data.push_back(pContents[i]);


        dosHeader = (IMAGE_DOS_HEADER*)&data[0];

        if (dosHeader->e_magic == IMAGE_DOS_SIGNATURE)
        {
            ntHeader = (IMAGE_NT_HEADERS*)((DWORD)&data[0] + dosHeader->e_lfanew);

            if(ntHeader->Signature == IMAGE_NT_SIGNATURE)
            {
                sectionHeader = IMAGE_FIRST_SECTION(ntHeader);

                if(sectionHeader != NULL)
                {
                    for (unsigned int i = 0; i < ntHeader->FileHeader.NumberOfSections; i++)
                    {
                        printf("In section %s %d/%d\n", sectionHeader->Name, i, ntHeader->FileHeader.NumberOfSections);

                        if(bAdjust == true)
                        {
                            if(sectionHeader->PointerToRawData > dwDataPointer)
                            {
                                sectionHeader->PointerToRawData += 0x1000;
                                //sectionHeader->VirtualAddress += 0x1000;
                            }
                        }

                        if(strcmp((char*)sectionHeader->Name, ".text") == 0)
                        {
                            BYTE* pTemp;

                            pTemp = new BYTE[0x1000];


                            char* szStartMessage = "This is the start";

                            for(int k = 0; k < strlen(szStartMessage); k++)
                                pTemp[k] = szStartMessage[k];

                            for(int k = strlen(szStartMessage); k < 0x1000; k++)
                                pTemp[k] = k;


                            data.insert(data.begin() + sectionHeader->PointerToRawData + sectionHeader->SizeOfRawData, pTemp, pTemp + 0x1000);

                            dwDataPointer = sectionHeader->PointerToRawData;

                            ntHeader->OptionalHeader.SizeOfCode += 0x1000;
                            ntHeader->OptionalHeader.BaseOfData += 0x1000;
                            sectionHeader->SizeOfRawData += 0x1000;

                            bAdjust = true;
                        }

                        sectionHeader++;
                    }
                }

                ofstream out;

                out.open("C:\\test2.exe", ios::out | ios::binary);

                if(out.is_open() == true)
                {
                    out.write((char*)&data[0], data.size());
                    out.close();
                }
                else
                    printf("Couldn't write\n");
            }
        }
    }

    delete[] pContents;

    printf("Done\n");

    return 0;
}
```

I read Minesweeper into a vector of bytes. I then insert 0x1000 bytes to the bottom of the .text section. I increase all the relevant offsets by 0x1000 including the pointers of the other sections that come after it.

However, when I view the process in RAM. It seems to only show 1024 (0x400) of the bytes I inserted. The end seems to be truncated by whatever comes next.
Possibly the .data section since its virtual address is 0x5000.

How can I increase the size of the .text section?

Answer (score 0):

You haven't changed where the sections load in memory, so yes, the following sections(s) will be loaded over the end your expanded .text section.

What you're trying to do isn't possible in the general case. You can't insert anything into the middle of the executable because you need to change the load address of everything that follows. Changing the load address of a section will invalidate any pointers to that point to anything within the section, as they'll still point to the location in memory where the section used to be.

Comment: What is everything I would have to fix to increase the size of the .text section